# In React js, Useareacttoprint to print a pdf and make a heading on each page

Tags: reactjs, pdf, frontend

Can anyone help me out with this,

I am adding a print feature on my webpage by which the list on the webpage will be printed/made into pdf (multiple pages).

I need to add headings of the list on each page of printed pdf, how can I do this,

If anyone doesn't get the requirement please feel free to ask.

I have used mui data grid and resulted pdf is have a list heading only on first page.

I have tried useReactToPrint but don't know how to get that result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.